# Pass variable to php to download mysql csv file to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

My aplication downloads a file, through a php script which is all doing fine.
However, I can only download the file to Android if I use ACTION_PICK intent, which opens the browser but I can't pass any parameters/variables to the php.

I would like to do 2 things:

1. Download the file through php without open Android Browser
2. Pass parameters/variables to the php so that I can select which mysql query to preform

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using an intent instead of an HTTP call? Do you want to use the Android download manager?

Comment: @Bastien Léonard No, I don't know how to do it any other way. Can you help me

Comment: Here is a page that shows how to make a HTTP call: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html You can pass parameters in the URL query string and you receive a string with the result of the request. Would that work for you?

Comment: Well, I'm kindda a newbie and that's very confusing for me. Isn't there a more simple way. I tried to use htttpconnection but no result.

Comment: Yeah, HttpURLConnection would work too. You would received an InputStream instead of a string, which would be a bit more difficult but more efficient for large response. And then you wouldn't need to download and install an additional library. I suggest you use HttpURLConnection and google how to convert an input stream to a string.